# Magento: I want to modify the menu to show only product pages and not the home page

Tags: magento

I have a wordpress blog with a static home page, a blog, and links in the menu to other offsite server pages (IDX) for a real estate website. I want to add several Magento Product pages to my WP menu, which I know how to do. I have not moved the Magento install to my online server yet.

The problem I have in my local machine testing setup, is that Magento has it's own home page, which I think will conflict with my WP home page or at least be confusing, and there is no content on the Magento home page I want to use. I use the Magento categories and products to display information, and then have links back to my WP site.  I do not use the shopping cart or checkout, and have successfully removed those at the Magento product pages.

I want to find a way to just show the product pages on the Magento Menu,not the home page when a user enters my Magento area. Most of the help on this shows how to add menus and products to the Magento Home page, not how to hide the home page in the menu.

A great Magento menu for me would be: /Product Category/Sub Category/

Thanks for any help or leads to help on this.
Bryan.

Comment: Have you tried have both wordpress and magento on your test machine together? There will be bigger problems to solve with your `.htaccess` file before worrying about menus.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the option to put a redirectmatch on your magento home so that it goes to your Wordpress home, or a category/product/anything page.
Also check out the existing Wordpress Magento integrations in Magento Connect. Some are very clever.